# Restrict location to just one IP in vhosts not working

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost, apache2.4

I am trying to restrict the access to a specific location for just one IP address in the vhosts file but for some reason it is not working. This for apache 2.4.29.

Here is my vhosts file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName subdomain.example.com
                Redirect / https://subdomain.example.com/
        </VirtualHost>

        <VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName subdomain.example.com
                ServerAlias example.com
                <Location />
                        <RequireAll>
                                Require all granted
                        </RequireAll>

                        AllowMethods DELETE GET POST PUT HEAD
                </Location>

                <Location /admin>
                        Require ip XX.XX.XX.XX
                </Location>

        </VirtualHost>

        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName subdomain.example.com
                ServerAlias example.com
                <Location />
                        <RequireAll>
                                Require all granted
                        </RequireAll>
                        AllowMethods DELETE GET POST PUT HEAD
                </Location>

                <Location /admin>
                        Require ip XX.XX.XX.XX
                </Location>
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And this is my apache.conf

```
<Directory />
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Feel free to suggest alternatives - I thought this could also be done via `mod_security`

.htaccess is not an option in the case.

Thank you!

Comment: Just a note... Have you restarted Apache? I forgot it several times... :)

Comment: Enable mod_security logging: https://www.feistyduck.com/library/modsecurity-handbook-free/online/ch04-logging.html

Comment: What are you requesting? What's the result?

Comment: Have you enable the module named "authz_host_module" ?

Comment: You have 2 VirtualHosts with the exact same ServerName.  Apache will read the configuration and only use the first one for matching requests.  So anything going to subdomain.example.com will always be redirected.